# Casting an enum works when declaring a specific enum entry, but not when retrieving from a dictionary

Tags: c#, casting, enums

When one declares an enumeration with a base type uint, it is possible to cast it to an int when you know exactly which item you are converting. However, when you have a Dictionary and retrieve one of the enum items from it, you cannot do this cast.

Why does this happen?

For example:

Enum:

```
public enum IncrementScheduleMask
{
    Sunday = 0x01,
    Monday = 0x02,
    Tuesday = 0x04,
    Wednesday = 0x08,
    Thursday = 0x10,
    Friday = 0x20,
    Saturday = 0x40,
}
```

This will work:

```
bool Sun = true;
ulong weeklyMask = 0;
if (Sun)
    weeklyMask |= (int)IncrementScheduleMask.Sunday;
```

But this wont:

```
public static List<string> DaysOfTheWeek = new List<string>{
    "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"
};

public static Dictionary<string, IncrementScheduleMask> DaysOfTheWeekMasks = new Dictionary<string, IncrementScheduleMask>()
{
    { "Sun", IncrementScheduleMask.Sunday },
    { "Mon", IncrementScheduleMask.Monday },
    { "Tue", IncrementScheduleMask.Tuesday },
    { "Wed", IncrementScheduleMask.Wednesday },
    { "Thu", IncrementScheduleMask.Thursday },
    { "Fri", IncrementScheduleMask.Friday },
    { "Sat", IncrementScheduleMask.Saturday }
};

ulong weeklyMask = 0;
Action<string> _CompileWeekDays = new Action<string>(dayName =>
{

        IncrementScheduleMask iMask = DaysOfTheWeekMasks[dayName];

        weeklyMask |= (int)iMask;
});
DaysOfTheWeek.ForEach(_CompileWeekDays);
```

I've already gone ahead with another solution, but I wanted to know why one works and not the other. If you should not be able to cast like this, then shouldn't it be the same both ways?

Comment: You never declare `fullMask` in your second form... and if you were trying to use `weeklyMask`, that's never initialized. Please give a short but *complete* example which fails...

Comment: I guess he meant weeklyMask |= instead of weeklyMask !=

Comment: Edited to fix typos, sorry guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your enum is based on `int`, not `uint` as you claim.

The difference between the two situations is that in the first one you have a ***constant*** conversion. You *can* convert from `int` to `ulong` implicitly with constants (literals) because the compiler can see that the values are non-negative.

In the second case, you don't have compile-time constants. Therefore the conversion from `int`, a type that *could* be negative, to `ulong`, a non-signed type, ***must*** be explicit, not implicit.

In both cases, it is natural to change the `(int)` cast to `(ulong)`.

---

Here's a simpler example:

```
// will work:
const int e = 1;
ulong weeklyMask = e;  // OK from int to ulong, constant
```

Versus:

```
// will not work:
int e = 1;
ulong weeklyMask = e;  // illegal from int to ulong, needs explicit cast
```